# Beta distribution on discrete data

Tags: probability, beta-distribution

Suppose that my data $y \in \{0,0.1,\ldots,1\}$. What are the consequences of modeling that data as continuous, i.e., as if $y \in [0,1]$, by using the beta distribution? Is there a version of the beta distribution that can account for this?

Comment: When you say $\{0,0.1,…,1\}$ do you mean the data is all multiples of 0.1, or something else? If so, how does it arise - as ratios of counts, or some other way? Why do you want to use a beta, rather than something else?

Comment: Yup, that's what I mean.

Comment: Is it a set of counts (out of 10) divided by 10, or rounded values, or something else? Why a beta?

Comment: The reason why I am going for a beta is that the underlying interpretation of the variable is the chance that something will happen.

Comment: @BrashEquilibrium No, the beta distribution models the likelihood on a bias $p$ of a Bernoulli random variable induced by its realizations.  It's not appropriate for this data.

Comment: Beta is not appropriate, but the beta-binomial is (more) appropriate. See checked answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could model the variable $10Y \sim {\rm BetaBinomial}(n = 10, a, b)$.  Specifically, if $X \sim {\rm BetaBinomial}(n, a, b)$, then $$\Pr[X = x] = \frac{\Gamma (b+1) \Gamma (a+n) \Gamma (n+x) \Gamma (a+b-x)}{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (n) \Gamma (x+1) \Gamma (b-x+1) \Gamma (a+b+n)}.$$  The only restriction on the parameters $a,b$ is that they be positive; $n$ must be a nonnegative integer; and $x \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n\}$.  This PMF has many nice properties:  see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution

Comment: right after I asked this question, I did some digging and this is the solution I decided for myself. Came back and here it is. Check please!

Answer (score 4):

It is rather easy to create a discrete version of the beta distribution, and in its standard interval from zero to unity. In your case the support is $Y \in \{0,0.1,\ldots,1\}$.  So consider the probability mass function, with $j=\{0,1,...,10\}$

$$P(Y=j/10;\alpha;\beta) = \frac{(j/10)^{\alpha-1}[1-(j/10)]^{\beta -1}}{ \sum_{j=0}^k(j/10)^{\alpha-1}[1-(j/10)]^{\beta -1}} $$

but with $\alpha \ge 1,\;\; \beta \ge 1$, and using $0^0 \equiv 1$.

It is characterized by the same flexibility in shape than the continuous version (bar the "U-shape" which would require parameters smaller than unity).

Comment: Alecos, if you have an argument for why this is superior to @heropup's solution, I'd love to here it and would totally consider switching if your argument gets validated.

Comment: It is not. My answer is just a first step towards a direct discretization of the beta distribution, so it remains to be checked and studied, for results, moments, properties to be derived for it etc. On the other hand, the Beta-Binomial is an already well-studied distribution. On a first check, they seem to provide roughly analogous results regarding the shape of the pmf graph.